# How can I send multi-part messages by gsmcomm

Tags: c#

i wanna send a sms by gsmcomm that lenght of text is more than 140 characters.
i used this code

```
pdu = new SmsSubmitPdu(strSMS, cellNO, "");
gsmComm.SendMessage(pdu);
```

but they have an error ....

How can I send multi-part messages?

Comment: You should include the exact error in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you using gsmcomm open source github library, it does not split your text into 70 characters in unicode and 70 character in 8bit,
it only using AT command to sending message to port.
You should split it yourself.

Comment: خیلی ممنونم علیرضای عزیز
راه بهتری به جز ATCommand سراغ داری ؟ :D

Comment: For working on all gsm modems there is not other standard.

Comment: thank you alireza.
i wish you the best